# I am not able to crack this algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I was just practicing some question from HackerEarth. I tried this question but not able to grab the logic. As per the tags this includes dynamic programming recursion.

Can anybody figure out how to answer this question and explain it to me?

https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/avoid-boredom/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no sign of effort done by the questionere.

Comment: Show us your code. What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Basic dynamic programming. Because of the requirement you keep the initial order.

`V[x,y]` is the maximum sum achieved if you've selected y subjects already and the last one is x.

Obviously `V[x,1] = 0` for all x (selecting a single subject doesn't give you anything for the sum.

`V[x,y] = max_a(V[a,y-1] + abs(A[a] - A[x]), for a  in y-1, x-1` That is for all the others you look before them for for the best option.

The solution is `max_x(V[x, M])`.

For implementation you just need to make sure that you don't pick some invalid cells (V[0, 3] should be invalid, you can't pick 3 items if the last one is 0).